# Ma'aseh Oreg on Mishnah Machshirin

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, mishna, maseches-machshirin

Artscroll edition of Machshirin refers to something called Ma'aseh Oreg making a comment on mishnah 5:7. I can't find any work of this name on either Hebrewbooks, Otzar or Bar Ilan. Or indeed Google... Can anyone help?

Comment: https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990011997670205171/NLI

Comment: https://books.google.co.il/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92.html?id=pwx8NQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: Author ישראל גוקוביצקי
Publisher מוציא לאור לא ידוע, 1983

Comment: @DannySchoemann It just seems quite unlikely that this book about weaving is the one being referred to though? What does a mishnah in Machshirin (about maritime life) have to do with weaving?

Comment: Why not? It's a Mishna about various types of nets:  בַּמְּצוֹדוֹת וּבָרְשָׁתוֹת וּבַמִּכְמָרוֹת - sounds like a perfect fit.

Comment: You can buy it for $12 at https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92

Comment: @DannySchoemann I've just searched it on Otzar and it doesn't mention this masechet at all...

Comment: So you need to edit the question and exclude the Otzar. Besides, various types of netting are mentioned in various places, they are not specific to this Mishna.

Comment: Apologies @DannySchoemann but I don't think your deduction is right - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sefer was authored by [Rav Yitzchak Isaac Safrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komarno_(Hasidic_dynasty)#:%7E:text=Rabbi%20Yitzchak%20Eisik%20Yehuda%20Yechiel%20Safrin%20of%20Komarno%2C%20known%20as,(my%20Teacher%20and%20inspirer)%2C), the [Komarno Rebbe](https://yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Zhidachov-Komarno_Hasidic_Dynasty).

> Yitsḥak Ayzik of Komarno was the most interesting and original of the dynasty’s leaders in its second generation. In effect, he founded a new Hasidic dynasty, that of Komarno, and was known by the name Safrin, whereas other members of the family were called Eichenstein. After his marriage he studied with his father-in-law, Avraham Mordekhai of Pińczów, but when his teacher died he became a prominent disciple of his uncle, Tsevi Hirsh. Eventually the dynasty was known by the double name Zhidachov-Komarno.
>
> When Tsevi Hirsh died, Yitsḥak Ayzik (Aleksander-Sender’s son) moved from Zhidachov to Komarno, where his father had served as rabbi. Yitsḥak Ayzik of Komarno wrote many books—most of which were published in his lifetime—expounding the Torah, the Mishnah, and the Zohar. The principal thrust of his writing is mystical, and as the title pages proclaim, his works are based on the teachings of the Besht, the Zohar, and Yitsḥak Luria. In addition to his kabbalistic texts, Yitsḥak Ayzik also wrote a book of meditative visions, Megilat setarim (1999), modeled after the visionary texts of Ḥayim Vital, revealing what he calls the source of his soul and hinting that he is the Messiah of the House of Joseph.

The Ma'aseh Oreg is contained in the full set of Mishnayos Komarno as seen [here](https://houses.bidspirit.com/ui/lotPage/source/catalog/auction/9129/lot/17617/Complete-Set-of-Mishnayos-Komarno?lang=en). You can access it on Otzar [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=8873&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15979592246616602) (but you will have to pay for the privilege of seeing it in Machshirin as it is beyond the free page allowance).

---

**EDIT**

Following on from my answer, I can now prove my assertion:

Firstly, the Artscroll Mishna Machshirin 5:7 - p.181, on the opening words of Mishna 7 ("המים עולין בספינה"), the notes write:

> The reason for this ruling is similar to that of the case concerning  one who crossed a river that obstructed his path ([Mishnah 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makhshirin.5.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), in which case the water that adheres to the person's body is not fit to be *machshir*. That is, he has no need for the water; to the contrary, he would have preferred to avoid this river altogether. he crossed the river only because he had no other way to proceed. Similarly, a person travelling by boat has no need for the water that adheres to the boat and is interested only in reaching his destination (**Ma'aseh Oreigh**; see further Mishnah Acharonah)

One can see the text below of the Ma'aseh Oreig which clearly echoes this explanation written in the Artscroll notes:

[image]

Comment: You gave the perfect answer why no votes?

Comment: Feel free to get the ball rolling:-)

Comment: You seem always to write good posts. I suppose you were in Gateshead. I have had long arguments in chat about the voting system. I must add again this is the kind of answer what is always needed. Not lomdish those are no good for here, but like yours which are very interesting.

Comment: Thank you v much I appreciate the nice feedback! Whilst I have been zoche to go to Gateshead many times I actually learnt in yeshivah in eretz yisroel. Thanks again

Comment: @Zarka - does this answer your question?